# Django - Annotate sum of duration in hour

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-annotate

I have a field Time with type DurationField and I want to sum the values and convert it into decimal hour

```
Task.objects.all().annotate(total=Sum('Time'))
```

For example if total = timedelta(seconds=5400) I want to get 1.5 hours

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the duration by `timedelta(hours=1)`, so you render this with:

```
mytask.total / timedelta(hours=1)
```

This then produces:

```
>>> timedelta(seconds=5400) / timedelta(hours=1)
1.5
```